# Need code to get current DB name in access 2007

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have an access 2007 application with split database (accdb). Now I am trying to use the same application for 2 different accounts. I have already added code to relink the database. Now what I am trying to achieve in here is that it should only try to re-link dbs if the chosen account name is different from the current db. I have tried CurrentDb.Name but it returns the name of the application and not the database.

So, I have an application as A; and two databases with names as A_be and B_be. I would need code to let me know if A is currently linked to A_be or B_be.

Could someone please help with this. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

On further research I figured a way out.. it may not be the best code for it but it will work. Doing a copy-paste below for reference.

Dim strFullPath As String

strFullPath = Mid(DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0).TableDefs("AnyTableName").Connect, 11)
MsgBox Dir(strFullPath)